# replacing content from cache to document directory?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

In my Document folder i am having a folder named folder1 in that folder i am having css,js,main.html etc.. i am opening the main.html in webview....If any updates are done in server i am downloading folder2 and unzipping it in cache directory For example: i am having css,js ,main.html in folder1 in document directory and a new update is done in server and i am downloading folder2 and unzipping in cache directory in folder2 i am having css only now i want to compare these folder1 and folder2 content if equal means in this example css is present in both the folders i want to delete css in document directory folder1 and i want to replace the css which is in folder2 to folder1...this is the process next time if any update is done then i may download js not css at that time i want to replace only js.can any one help how to check the content and replace ... please help me its imp to me

Comment: be specific... and tells us you want

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore....you didn't understand the above process aa???..

Comment: Because it's very long content and no one have much time to read it. Read [FAQ] to improve the quality of your question

Comment: i want to replace the content from caches to document dynamically...@Inder Kumar Rathore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you are using Documents directory to store the CSS and HTML to be loaded inside UIWebView and Caches directory to unzip and store latest CSS and HTML files from the server. After unzipping, you want to compare the contents of CSS and JS files in Caches folder with the contents of CSS and JS files in Documents folder and replace if they have changed.

There are 2 steps in this:

1. Standardizing files names across both folders so that you know which file from Caches directory should be compared with which file from Documents directory. Give the same names to files that are to be compared.
2. On fetching the file from server and unzipping in Caches folder, you can get use NSFileManager class to access the same file (names are same as mentioned in point 1) in your Documents directory and then read it in an NSString and then compare that with another NSString that contains your Caches folder content. If the comparison returns equal you can skip. Else, you can use

> ```
>  NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
>
>  [manager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath(CachesDir) toPath:destinationPath(DocumentsDir) error:&error]
> ```

This will copy your latest unzipped item from CacheDirectory to Documents Directory.

However, you may want to double check saving content in Documents Directory as it is backed-up on iCloud account to which the device is mapped. Please read about this further.

Comment: You should use `[NSFileManager defaultManager]`.